# Regex for decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a validation on numeric string with javascript , to ensure the number has at most 3 digit after decimal and at most 3 digit before decimal.

Valid

```
111

111.11

11.1

1.1

11.111
```

Invalid

```
1111

11.4444

1111.11

1111.1111
```

Comment: Interesting! Did you also have a question?

Comment: And where is the research you have done on this? What have you tried that isn't working as expected? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: What about negative numbers? Is `.111` valid or does it have to be `0.111`? Once you've answered those question, head on over to http://www.regular-expressions.info/, read everything and convert your requirements into an expression. From there you can use [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: What about leading zeroes? Is `0.1` valid? What about `0001.1`? Or `000`?

Comment: Try something like this [`^\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/KQkjUz/3)

Comment: @Gurman why a comment and not an answer?

Comment: I am trying to use  ^([0-9] {1,3}+[0-9]{1,3})?$

Comment: Robby 0.1 is valid. But 0001.1 is not valid.

Comment: @Phil.111 is not valid it is required to enter alteast one number before decimal.0.111 is valid

Comment: @gurman its not working.

Comment: @Phil Because the counter-questions raised by others are valid. Not all the requirements were properly mentioned. Hence, left a comment which ultimately was found to be "not working" by OP.

Comment: @NavneetKaur As per your inputs, the regex is working(see the link provided). May be it didn't work for the requirements you didn't mention here

Comment: @NavneetKaur again, **what about negative numbers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^(?=\d)(?!0(?![.]))(?:\d{0,3})(?:[.]\d{1,3})?$
```

[***Regex Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/BDQHqr/6/)

Regex Breakdown

```
^ #Start of string
 (?=\d) #Lookahead to ensure there is a dot or number
 (?!0(?![.])) #Negative lookahead to ensure there is no 0 in starting followed by .
 (?:\d{0,3}) #Match at most three digits before decimal
 (?:[.]\d{1,3})? #Match at most three digits after decimal. If there is a dot there should be at least one digit after dot
$ #End of string
```

Comment: OP says "0.111" is valid

Comment: @Phil updated the regex